# toggle 12v as high and 11v as low for arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, relay

a little diff question, have googled to get clues but apparently I don't know what exactly to seats for.

Im trying to turn on a led with arduino when a external source triggers 12v. basically that ext source swaps between 12v when active and 11v when inactive. I hoped for that 11v to be 0v so I could use transistor or relay with arduino but unfortunately the low state on external device is 11v.

how can I check with arduino when the ext source is at 11v and how do I tell arduino that this is the low state. I just want to light up a led with arduino whenever the ext source is 12v and kill the led light when it's 11v.
I tried with 2 1M resistors on that 11v but I got it down to 9v and I don't like the idea of chaining resistors.

is there any other possible components that I could use for this purpose ?

Comment: but does the arduino analog handle 11-12v ? I'd assume it doesn't :/

Comment: A couple of resistors wired as a potential divider should bring the voltage into range.

Comment: I had no success with 1M resistor  didtnt even get supply down  below 12v :S

Comment: One resistor wont do what you want see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Answer (score 2):

The part you're looking for is a comparator. Set a threshold with resistors at 11.5 volts. The arduino is not required here, but could still be used if additional behavior is desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fly7lY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatives:

- There is probably a diode-based option, but the comparator will be simpler.
- As mentioned by others, you can use a resistor divider into an A/D and then do the threshold logic in software.

Comment: which comparator would be suitable for me ?

Comment: What voltages do you have handy?

Comment: arduino runs on 5v and the external device is 13.8v Max  and I assume somewhere around (Max) 5-10amp... is the turning signal light  that I what to get that signal from into arduino

Comment: @DanelK When the external device is running at 13.8 volts is the "operating good" output at 12V or 13.8 volts?

Comment: @DanelK would you like to eliminate the arduino from the design if possible?

Comment: @Houston fortney, sorry, I guess 13.8v cause the vehicle electronics run between 10v and 13.8v depending on the battery health

Comment: sorry for this project I'm not able to eliminate arduino at all :/

Comment: Then power the comparator with the arduino's supply. It can be pretty much any comparator maybe [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TS391RILT/497-11276-2-ND/2673242)?

Comment: Also: You will need to scale the voltage with resistors to within the supply. I'll add a schematic as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for you time with the schematic. Ill try this out (when possible) and ill let you know the results :)

Comment: Tho one more question, from what i understand, this comparator should work too ? I actually have 2 external sources so see if one or both are high/low.  https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/dx644212.pdf

Comment: That part has an open drain output. So you will need a pull-up to 5V on the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29150/discussion-between-danelk-and-houston-fortney).

Comment: Isnt that what would be suitable when arduino digital pin is set to INPUT ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a voltage divider and sense the voltage state using and analog to digital converter. If your paranoid place a 5.1v zener diode on the pin to protect it just in case. Also remember that sampling does take some current. The current is minuscule but it does limit the maximum value of the divider.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25NiJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use the above voltage divider schematics,,you should now be able to map 11v and 12v to some analog values in arduino,,you will have to do R&D with code to pull this off

Vr2=(Vin*R2)/(R1+R2)

Vr2=(12*10000)/(10000+100000)=1.0909V

Vr1=(Vin*R1)/(R1+R2)

Vr1=(12*100000)/(10000+100000)=10.909

hope this helps

Comment: correct me if I get this wrong, the 100k R reduces the +ve (12v) down to 10v... but arduino analog can handle Max 5V ?